# How can I get credit for answers I wrote in a sister site that were moved to superuser?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I answered these questions in SO before they were migrated to SU:

[How can I concatenate two files in Unix?](https://superuser.com/questions/228878/how-can-i-concatenate-two-files-in-unix)

[How to find the largest file in a directory?](https://superuser.com/questions/228853/how-to-find-the-largest-file-in-a-directory-closed)

My accounts are (or should be) linked.  Why don't I get credit for this?

Answer (score 4):

We just deployed a better method of tracking ownership across sites; you now own these answers.